# CSS div class not recognized unless defined

Tags: html, css

**Edit 2: I figured out the issue, in the main html, the one I'm working on, I had forgotten I wrote all the media definitions at the top of the file, I didn't realize the CSS is read from top to bottom. Sorry for any confusion.
Thanks to user @Pete for the further explanation!.**

I'm learning web design and this div class is not having it's CSS applied  unless I define that is inside another div. Is this normal behavior? shouldn't it just pick up any classes with that name and apply the rule?.

The code should change it from being **logo** and **nav** next to each other in 20%/80% to **logo** being above **nav** both in 100%.

TLDR: Is it normal that I have to define **header > .logo**
 like this? If not, where could I have gone wrong?

Currently coding with Dreamweaver CC 2018, I can provide more details if needed.

I'm sorry if this is very basic but I'm learning HTML and CSS currently and I haven't seen this explained anywhere else.

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  header>.logo {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  header>nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <nav>MENU</nav>

</header>
```

Edit: Added code snippet as best I could since it's the first time I use this site.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `header > .logo` is more specific than `.logo` so it's rules will take precedence, you should find that if you change the second selector to `header > .logo` that the rules will take effect as it has the same weight as the earlier selector but is later in the document.

Comment: I don't get it. Wihch div do you mean? `.logo`? Please add an [MCVE]

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I would expect the part in the media query to be more specific (if it is not placed after the original) as it needs to overwrite the original, but without seeing the code properly in a [mcve] we can only guess why it is not working

Comment: @pete that is likely, my comment's aim is for the OP to understand why this may happen given the information provided, we'd definitely need an example to answer properly

Comment: @Makiabel Ok now we have a snippet, your code works as it should - 2 divs side by side in above 480px, one above the other under 480px.  What's the issue?

Comment: @Pete I'll edit the main post in a second but going through the main html where I had this issue I realized I'm putting the media stuff at the very beginning of the css file, when I move it below the generic definitions it works as intended. Sorry for the confusion I didn't realize the CSS is read from top to bottom.

Comment: Yeas, always put media queries after the original css as it needs to overwrite the css - that way you can use the original selector to make it easier to maintain too (by using a more specific selector, it means you would also may need to be more specific in other media queries that may also match that one but needs to override it and it also becomes harder to see which one it is meant to be overriding)

Comment: This is a [good article about specificity and order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) - the order bit is kind of covered in part b of How to override !important

Comment: Yeah, I would stick away from using `!important` as much as possible. This can lead to a lot of confusion for the future you or anyone else that is involved in coding it. It is hard to find broken code when `!important` is used.